# How to run multiple playbooks in order with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm working on several Ansible playbooks to spin up a new server instance.  There are approximately 15 different playbooks I need to run in a specific order to successfully spin up a server.

My initial thought was to write a shell script that executes `ansible-playbook playbook_name.yml` and duplicate it one entry for each playbook I need to run.

Is there a smarter/better way to do this using a master playbook and if so what would it look like (examples are appreciated).

I could write one monolithic playbook that does it all but there are some plays that run as root first then as a sudo user later.

Comment: use include in your main playbook https://web.archive.org/web/20150723003206/https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html

Comment: To handle the case of running as root then as a sudo user, you can use the [block](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) feature - put the `become:` part at end of each block.  You might need to create a new **play** to switch connection user from root to sudo user though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Build many sub-playbooks and aggregate them via include statements.

```
- include: playbook-one.yml
- include: playbook-two.yml
```

If your playbooks must run in order and if all of them are mandatory, build a main playbook and include files with tasks. A playbook should always be a closed process.

Comment: could you elaborate on the last part of your answer? what do you mean by "A playbook should always be a closed process." ?

Comment: Is there a way to specify all playbooks using regular expression? For Example: `- include : books/*.yml`

Comment: Looks like `include` is deprecated. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse.html I think `import_playbook: foo` is the right way to go, but I'm not super experienced.

Comment: @MikeVella "A playbook should always be a closed process" essentially means that each playbook should be unto itself and should be independently complete.  Nothing in playbook-a should be reliant or necessary from playbook-b.  Keep it all as together as possible.

Answer (score 34):

For newer versions of Ansible, you can build many sub-playbooks and aggregate them via import_playbook statements:

```
---
- import_playbook: A-systemd-networkd.yml
- import_playbook: B-fail2ban-ssh.yml
- import_playbook: C-enable-watchdog.yml
```

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to continue with B if A fails? 
A way other than setting ignore_errors: yes for every task in A ?

Answer (score 5):

From: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: play1

- name: Include a play after another play
  import_playbook: otherplays.yaml
```